# get substrings from a delimited string excepted the last one

Tags: regex

having  strings like

```
booboo-en
booboo-duck-en
booboo-the-duck-en
booboo-the-duck-so-nice-en
```

I tried to extract all the strings (whatever number of delimited groups) except the last one (`-en`) to get :

```
booboo
booboo-duck
booboo-the-duck
```

and so on...

Using

```
^((?:[^-]+-){2}[^-]+).*$
```

I can extract 2 groups , but I don't see how to modify it for any number of groups ...

Comment: It's not possible to create a regex with a variable number of captures (except possibly in perl).

Comment: which language or tool are you using?

Comment: You can also use lastIndexOf and substring utility to do this...

Comment: Is `-en` fixed at the end of each string ?

Comment: -en is not fixed , but I realized that it's always the same length ( 3) , so I may go to a substring extraction based on string.length - 3...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
^.*(?=-[^-]*$)
```

This will match the string up until just before the final dash:

```
^       # Start of string
.*      # Match any number of characters
(?=     # until it's possible to match:
 -      #  a dash
 [^-]*  #  followed only by characters other than dashes
 $      #  until the end of the string.
)       # (End of lookahead assertion)
```

Answer (score 1):

why are you using regex for this?

at least any scripting language has a split primitive

they usually return arrays

combining split and removing the last element of an array is trivial

Comment: my original code was using a regex, but it's true that there are many other ways to do it